# Make a promise that resolves when a specific function is called

Tags: jestjs

I have a module with an exposed run() function that queues as background task, and I want to await in the test until this background task has been processed.
The background task process function is also exposed in this module, so I am thinking I could just spy on this process function and add a promise to await when it has run.

The module is provided by an external package that I don't have control over, so I have no way of changing the api.

But I don't see a way to do this with jest.spyOn. Does anyone know a way?

```js
function makeModule() {
  const data = {}
  return {
    process() {
      data['banana'] = true
    },
    run() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        process()
      }, someArbitraryTime)
    },
    data,
  }
}

test() {
  const module = makeModule();
  const spy = jest.spyon(module, 'process');
  module.run();
  await spy; // I want to do this
  expect(module.data.banana).toBe(true)
}
```

I have a helper that allow me to solve the problem like this:

```js
function resolveAfterFnCall(obj, fnName) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const original = obj[fnName];
    obj[fnName] = async function (...args) {
      const result = await original.call(obj, ...args);
      resolve();
      return result;
    };
  });
}

test() {
  const module = makeModule();
  const promise = resolveAfterFnCall(module, "process");
  module.run();
  await promise; // Yay
  expect(module.data.banana).toBe(true)
}
```

This is great. Buuuut I would like to see if there is already something built into jest to handle this.